# How to convert byte array to int/long

Tags: java, android

I have these byte arrays:
[image: Byte Arrays]

I have to order to little endian before to convert.

In first case, I do the conversion easyly:

```
byte[] serial = {-91, -101, 62, 55};
int serialNumber = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(serial).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
//serialNumber == 926849957 //Nice, works!!!!
```

In second case, the conversion doesn't works:

```
byte[] serial = {-45, 12, 115, -28};
int serialNumber = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(serial).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
//serialNumber == -462222125 //Wrong conversion. The right answer is 3832745171.
```

The number 3832745171 is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but if I try to convert to long I got a problem too.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Try to convert byte arrays to int/long types.

Comment: Int64 if available?

Comment: I tried, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3832745171 is the value if you could use unsigned integer, but it's not a valid value of a signed integer.
It differs from -462222125 by `Math.pow(2,32)`

From the example in http://www.java2s.com/example/java/java.nio/get-unsigned-int-from-bytebuffer.html it seems possible to use a value in "long" to store the "Unsigned Integer" value.

Combining the logic in the link with your code, it would be like
`long serialNumber = ( java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(serial).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL)`

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] serial = {-45, 12, 115, -28};
int serialNumber = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(serial).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

This gives you the only representable equivalent of that in a Java `int`.

If you want it as an unsigned value, it will only be able to fit in a `long`, but you can write

```
Integer.toUnsignedLong(serialNumber)
```

(That said, you *can* just store it in an int.  It's still the same value, it just does math differently and prints differently; you can convert it only when necessary.)

Comment: I tried, but I was not successful.